# Can someone suggest a better way to use configuration files in multiple environments

Tags: ssis, configuration-files

I want to standardize and parameterize values across multiple environments and not have to change the dtsx files at any point.

The pattern I am deciding to use is to run all packages from the DTEXEC program and to specify configuration file on the command line and put that all in a batch file. with a different batch file for each environment.

One requirement is the location for the configuration file cannot be in the same physcial drive location, ie all config files are in D:\SSIS\config files. The main reason is that the production machine has an E drive mapped and this is where the ssis packages live and operate from. And, the staging machine does not, and cannot have a drive mapped to E.

Also, we want all files to reside in same pattern across all environments. config files in one place, archive files in another, etc. And, to try to use one medium, meaning the file system is where we store the packages, config files and batch files, as opposed to having data and artifacts in the registry and environment variables.

Does anyone see a more direct approach that satisfies all the conditions?

There may not be one and I thank you for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how we're doing it - all config files on the file system, running packages using batch files that call `dtexec`, and passing config file locations to `dtexec` via parameters.

Watch out for a possible nasty gotcha, though. As [this Books Online article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500430.aspx) points out, `dtexec`'s behavior regarding command-line configurations changed between SSIS 2005 and SSIS 2008.